# Feedback e Iniciativas nos Sites Internacionais

Tags: debate

Esta é uma tradução do post [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/401803) (discussão que está tendo no [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com)). Basicamente, é uma proposta para melhorar a comunicação entre os sites internacionais e a empresa Stack Exchange (o próprio post explica melhor).

*<sup>Fiquem à vontade para melhorar a tradução.</sup>*

---

O objetivo final do Stack Overflow, com a ajuda da nossa comunidade, é construir uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para toda pergunta sobre programação. Junto com nossos bravos usuários, partimos em uma incrível aventura ao lançar sites do Stack Overflow em diferentes idiomas ao longo dos últimos anos.

[image]

E as coisas estão indo bem até agora! Se olharmos para estes sites como se fosse um único site internacional, é a segunda comunidade mais ativa depois do Stack Overflow em Inglês (baseado na métrica de perguntas por dia). Vendo nossos sites internacionais e o restante da rede Stack Exchange, posso ver claramente que falta uma coisa importante que todo site da rede tem, exceto os internacionais. Refiro-me ao "*Canal de comunicação bidirecional entre a empresa e a comunidade*".

#### Como a empresa e as comunidades se comunicam atualmente?

Desde 01/01/2018 (até 15/06/2018) foram postadas por funcionários da empresa:

- Meta Stack Exchange: 282 respostas.
- Meta Stack Overflow em Russo: 48 respostas.
- Meta Stack Overflow em Espanhol: 28 respostas.
- Meta Stack Overflow em Português: 10 respostas.
- Meta Stack Overflow em Japonês: 1 resposta.
- Meta Stack Overflow em Inglês: 412 respostas.

Para mim, parece que se algum funcionário não fala o idioma de uma comunidade, esta se torna  isolada do restante da rede. Não queremos que isso aconteça. Nossa filosofia de sucesso depende muito da nossa comunidade. Gradualmente fazemos dos nossos sites o melhor lugar da Internet para fazer perguntas e respondê-las, baseado no seu *feedback*. Sem uma maneira de falar com a comunidade e escutar nossos usuários, há poucas chances de melhorar algo.

#### Qual era o processo?

No início, havia um CM (*Community Manager*) bilíngue dedicado para cada site internacional. A forma que estes CM's trabalhavam com suas comunidades variavam de um site para outro. Cada site internacional tinha iniciativas e focos diferentes que quase nunca se cruzavam. Por isso, os CM's frequentemente tinham o mesmo trabalho para resolver problemas parecidos entre os sites internacionais. Muita energia poderia ter sido poupada se eles trabalhassem juntos.

#### Melhoria na comunicação

E se fizéssemos as coisas de outro jeito? E se fôssemos capazes de compartilhar iniciativas entre os sites internacionais, aproveitar a experiência de outras comunidades, e agir baseado no *feedback* de todos os sites? O primeiro passo nesta direção é estabelecer um canal de comunicação para troca de ideias, iniciativas e *feedback* entre a empresa e as comunidades, assim como entre as próprias comunidades.

O maior desafio é o fato de que todas as comunidades, incluindo a empresa, falam idiomas diferentes. Não é culpa de ninguém mas esta é a realidade. Por isso eu gostaria de compartilhar algumas ideias sobre como o canal de comunicação deveria funcionar.

## *Feedback* e Iniciativas nos Sites Internacionais

> **TL;DR**
>
> - Precisamos de um canal de comunicação entre a empresa e as comunidades internacionais, assim como entre as próprias comunidades. Atualmente, o melhor lugar para isso é o [MSE (*vulgo "metão"*)](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
> - Inglês será o idioma usado nas discussões no MSE e os sites internacionais manterão as discussões em seus próprios idiomas.
> - As iniciativas da empresa serão compartilhadas em Inglês no MSE e nós precisaremos da ajuda de voluntários para traduzi-las em seus respectivos metas.
> - As iniciativas da comunidade serão compartilhadas em seus respectivos metas e terão que ser traduzidas no MSE. Assim, elas poderão ser replicadas para os outros metas internacionais, conforme mencionado acima.
> - Manteremos sincronizadas as discussões em todos os metas.
> - Quando uma discussão em um meta internacional estiver quase concluída, precisaremos novamente de voluntários para fazer um resumo do que foi dito pela comunidade internacional e postá-lo como uma resposta no MSE.

[image]

Nos últimos anos tentamos implementar várias iniciativas interessantes no SOru ([exemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)), demos início a várias iniciativas sociais ([exemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)) e integramos/ativamos várias funcionalidades interessantes ([exemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6)). Incomoda-me que a maioria destas iniciativas não foi sugerida a outras comunidades internacionais. Acredito que é a mesma situação de outros sites: cada site tem suas próprias iniciativas que ninguém conhece, exceto os usuários do próprio site.

Isso pode levar a uma situação na qual muitas funcionalidades importantes para comunidades internacionais não são implementadas porque as iniciativas parecem ser necessárias apenas para um número relativamente pequeno de usuários (se olharmos individualmente para cada site internacional). Cada um dos sites internacionais não é grande sozinho, mas como eu disse, juntos somos a segunda comunidade mais ativa da rede. Se todas as comunidades precisam de alguma funcionalidade, eu espero que isso ganhe a prioridade correta. O primeiro passo, no entanto, é começar a discutir estas iniciativas juntos.

#### Como propagar uma iniciativa entre todos os sites internacionais?

Quando pensamos em meios de se comunicar entre todos os sites, precisamos levar em consideração o seguinte:

- O processo deve ser escalável. Imagine que há 100 sites internacionais. O processo deve funcionar para qualquer quantidade de sites sem dificuldades.
- O autor da iniciativa não fala todos os idiomas dos sites internacionais.
- Queremos que o maior número possível de pessoas vejam a iniciativa, incluindo usuários das várias comunidades em Inglês e os funcionários da empresa.
- Deveria ter uma maneira das comunidades internacionais discutirem as iniciativas em seus próprios idiomas.
- O resultado da discussão nos metas internacionais precisa ser compartilhado com o restante da rede, e particularmente com os outros sites internacionais.

Com isso tudo em mente, gostaria de compartilhar algumas ideias sobre como seria o processo:

1. O autor da iniciativa (seja um CM ou um usuário) precisa postar uma pergunta no MSE com alguma tag especial (digamos [international](/questions/tagged/international)). O post deve estar sempre em Inglês.
2. Usuários que conhecem os 2 idiomas podem se voluntariar para traduzir a pergunta e postar a tradução no meta internacional.
3. Quando a tradução é postada em um meta internacional, o voluntário adiciona um link para ela na pergunta do MSE. Por favor, também adicione o link da pergunta original do MSE na versão traduzida. Isso ajuda a manter as discussões sincronizadas.
4. Depois que a comunidade discutir a iniciativa, precisamos de voluntários para postar um resumo da discussão do meta internacional como uma resposta no MSE. O resumo deve estar em Inglês. Acho que seria uma boa ideia ter uma resposta como *community wiki*, que teria os resumos de todos os metas internacionais. Neste caso poderíamos aceitar esta resposta, mantendo-a no topo.
5. Se alguém tiver alguma opinião sobre a iniciativa, pode responder em qualquer um dos metas, incluindo o MSE.

No caso de ser uma iniciativa de uma comunidade, o processo é quase o mesmo, com uma diferença: a iniciativa começa no meta internacional e precisa ser traduzida para o Inglês e postada no MSE. O restante do processo é igual.

### Por favor, diga o que você acha

Queremos fazer dos nossos sites internacionais o melhor lugar da Internet para perguntas sobre programação nos idiomas nativos dos seus usuários. O primeiro passo é criar uma maneira das comunidades se comunicarem entre si e com a empresa. Se você tem alguma ideia para melhorar os processos com relação a este objetivo, por favor compartilhe sua opinião!

### A iniciativa nos sites internacionais

- Discussão no SOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3658/324
- Discussão no SOja: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2748
- Discussão no SOru: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7847
- Discussão no rus.se: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/339

**Atualização quanto ao nome da tag**

- [Internacionalização and localização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) são termos padronizados com significados bem conhecidos, e não acho que seriam os mais adequados para esta iniciativa.
- Stack Overflow internacional é um termo restrito. A iniciativa é sobre os sites internacionais. No meu entendimento, sites internacionais são aqueles cuja interface (*UI*) não está em Inglês. Atualmente temos os Stack Overflows internacionais e o [site de Língua Russa (Русский язык)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).
- A mim parece que quanto menor o nome da tag, melhor. Acho que poderia ser "international" (ou talvez "international*s*") pela mesma razão que não usamos "stack-overflow-site".

Ainda temos muitas questões quanto à nomenclatura. Se vocês tem ideias para melhorar os nomes das tags, por favor compartilhe!

Comment: Não seria melhor esperar o que vai ser decidido lá antes de traduzir pra cá? Essa discussão apenas aqui não faz sentido, o resultado dela, sim.

Comment: @Articuno Acho que postar aqui permite que pessoas que não falam inglês também possam discutir a proposta (já que elas não tem como fazer isso no MSE) e ao mesmo tempo já é uma forma ver se funciona essa ideia de manter a discussão em vários sites e tentar mantê-la sincronizada entre os mesmos (creio que é um bom teste, inclusive)

Comment: Concordo, é bom até pra mim que não sei inglês, mas digo isso porque lá já tem 2 sugestoes nas respostas, e a pergunta sem elas ficou meio deslocada, e ficará um pouco mais se outras sugestões interessantes forem dadas la.

Comment: @Articuno Concordo, creio que já encontramos o primeiro problema com relação à sincronização das discussões :(

Comment: Eu ia até comentar isso lá, mas novamente, o idioma não colabora. Mas de qualquer forma, vamos aguardar, a sua tradução é util sim, mas precisamos ver o que isso vai dar.

Comment: @Articuno Questionei isso lá e [a resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311#comment1033480_315311) basicamente é: *"Acho que temos que fazer o mínimo. Para mim as ideias de uma comunidade falam por si só. Precisamos de (1) espalhar a iniciativa para os sites (2) resumir o resultado das discussões em um lugar para tomar a melhor decisão. Seria bem difícil manter as respostas sincronizadas."* - Ou seja, cada site discute separadamente e no final todos levam um "resumão" para o MSE, onde será discutida a decisão "final". Não sei se é o melhor, mas parece ser "o que tem pra hoje"

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315387/167534 Desculpe aí pessoal, mas não vai dar pra eu postar isso em pt agora.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-will-be-released-soon o nicolas acabou de postar isso no chat.

Comment: Discussão relacionada: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315770/401803 (devemos traduzir esta aqui no meta também?)