# Design responsivo para sites internacionais será lançado em breve

Tags: novo-recurso

Traduzido a partir da publicação original no Meta: [Responsive design for international sites will be released soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315856/369699).

---

Estou animado em anunciar que os sites internacionais receberão o novo *design* responsivo na terça-feira, 25 de setembro.

[Na semana passada, todos os sites beta e sites não-designados receberam o novo tema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/):

> Coisas que devemos tomar ciência:
>
> - A navegação à esquerda está ativa na maioria das páginas (mas pode ser recolhida em um menu visitando as preferências do site - [instruções aqui](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/new-stock-theme-roll-out)).
> - O *layout* responsivo está ativo, o que permite que o site se ajuste à medida que as larguras do navegador mudam - sem rolagem lateral (algumas páginas ainda não foram atualizadas). Por enquanto, se você preferir a rolagem, poderá desativá-la clicando no link "desativar responsividade" no rodapé.
> - O sublinhado de links está ativo. Em um esforço para tornar os links mais visíveis, eles agora estão sendo sublinhados.
>
> ...
>
> A unificação de *layout* também nos permite melhorar mais facilmente os recursos existentes, como a [visualização de *tags*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/354333) e desenvolver novos recursos que foram solicitados há muito tempo, como [listas de perguntas personalizadas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer), que estão atualmente em teste. Adoraríamos ter mais recursos para todos vocês e é mais fácil gastarmos mais tempo trabalhando nos novos recursos e menos tempo reduzindo os *bugs* causados porque temos mais de 60 *layouts* de site muito diferentes.
>
> Isso é endereçado em uma [postagem do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) se você quiser mais detalhes.

Como parte da rede do Stack Exchange, os sites internacionais logo receberão o novo tema com a única diferença: não teremos período de teste, portanto, o tema estará disponível para todos.

Se você encontrar algum *bug* e quiser denunciá-lo, certifique-se de que os erros foram postados como respostas a essa pergunta. Se você tiver preocupações gerais, por favor, deixe comentários sobre a [postagem MSE existente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/)

Por favor, sinta-se livre para postar seu *feedback* da comunidade internacional aqui!

Comment: Publicação feita com base na [Feedback e Iniciativas nos Sites Internacionais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7308/5878)

Comment: «A navegação à esquerda está ativa na maioria das páginas (mas pode ser recolhida em um menu visitando as preferências do site» Muito bom, prefiro no menu.

Comment: @JorgeB. infelizmente não funciona bem para o meta. ainda é exibida uma lateral vazia

Comment: Sim, até no site mesmo fica um espaçamento - ou um alinhamento esquisito, no mínimo. Ele centraliza a página, mas como ela é menor que o cabeçalho, fica estranho.

Comment: @Articuno e Anderson isso é o menos ;)

Comment: Notei que os links nas postagens agora são sublinhados, mas não sei se isso veio junto com o novo layout responsivo. Na minha opinião o sublinhado melhorou bastante a visibilidade de um link em meio ao texto. (Edit: acabei de ler que isso veio junto sim rs.. não tinha reparado no texto).